# PHP Mysql PDO and unlock table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, table-locking

Should I manage the table unlock in case of an error in php (try/catch)? Or the lock is automatically released by PDO object ad the end of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Unless you're using a persistent connection, on the scripts's termination PDO will close the connection, and mysql, in turn will release all locks:

> PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
>
> If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session (transactional and nontransactional).
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Just for the record: It is always a good practice to release all resources (including locks in databases) when they are not in use anymore or at the end of the script or during error handling.

Comment: I think that the PHP PDO is a black box, I really can not understand what is happening about mysql connections and sessions...